# Resharper shows resolve errors with TypeScript unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, resharper

When I write Jasmine unit tests using TypeScript, Resharper 9.2 complains about any of the globals as being 'undefined'. So in the test below, 'describe', 'beforeEach', etc. all show up red and as undefined.

I run the tests from the command line (not Resharper) and they work no problem. It is just frustrating that it shows up as an error.

```
///<reference path="../../../../Scripts/typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts"/>
///<reference path="../../../../Scripts/typings/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts"/>
///<reference path="../../../../Scripts/typings/angularjs/angular-mocks.d.ts"/>

describe("CourseRequestModelFactory", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        angular.module('ngMessages');
        angular.mock.module({
            'tpts.grid.data.service': {
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Try cleaning the ReSharper cache, it helped me a few times

Comment: Thanks! Clearing cache was it.